# shortcut to define parameterless functions in clojure

Tags: clojure

I am searching for a shortcut to define parameterless functions in clojure:

```
=> (def x (fn [] (println "test")))
#'x
=> (x)
test
nil
=> (def y (println "test"))
test
#'y
=> (y)
NullPointerException   core/eval2015 (form-init5842739937514010350.clj:1)
```

I would really like to avoid typing the `fn []`. I know about the lambda notation `#()` but it requires at least one parameter. I would use them in a GUI binding to handle button click events where I don't care about the event itself, I just need to know the button was clicked.

Comment: I don't know where you got the idea #() required an argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
user> (def y #(println "test"))
#'user/y
user> (y)
test
```

Comment: well, i'll be damned. i was sure i had it fail once where it would say something like 'can't determine the arity' and i thought i MUST use % if it's a lambda.. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to noisesmith's response (which is the right answer to the question), in this particular case you could also do:

```
(def y (partial println "test"))
```

which would print `test` when called as `(y)`, or `test hello` when called as `(y "hello")`.